# Generic Dao with Spring data

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Data Repositories and custom Repositories on a Spring boot project, but I want to add Generic Repository for the customs.

This is `GenericCustomRepositoy` :

```
public interface GenericCustomRepositoy<T, ID> {

    List<T> findByFields(Class<T> clazz, List<Pair<String, Object>> fieldValue, List<Pair<String, Boolean>> orderBy);
}
@Repository
public class GenericCustomRepositoyImpl<T, ID> implements GenericCustomRepositoy<T, ID> {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    public List<T> findByFields(Class<T> clazz, List<Pair<String, Object>> fieldValues, List<Pair<String, Boolean>> orderBy) {

        final CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        final CriteriaQuery<T> cq = cb.createQuery(clazz);
        final Root<T> root = cq.from(clazz);

        ........................

        return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }
```

This is My Repository :

```
@Repository
public interface AdresseLivraisonRepository extends JpaRepository<AddressEntity, Integer>, GenericCustomRepositoy<AddressEntity, Integer> {

}
```

I have this exception when i wont to run the application :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adresseLivraisonRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property fields found for type AddressEntity!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
```

There is something I'm doing wrong!

I changed my code and I added a custom repository that extends the Generic but I get the same exception.

This is the new repository :

```
@Repository
public interface AdresseLivraisonRepository extends JpaRepository<ForwardingAddressEntity, Integer>, AdresseLivraisonCustomRepository {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I changed my generic classes by Spring Data JpaSpecificationExecutor, it does what I want to do with generics [Advanced Spring Data JPA - Specifications and Querydsl](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/)

Answer (score 1):

The name of your custom query method follows the naming conventions of the Spring Data JPA Repositories. So Spring Data JPA tries to generate a query-method for it during startup.

Try to rename your method to something else, like `genericFindByFields(...)`